# Convertendo vetor de char para string - C++

Tags: c++, string, array, char

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string vet[10], aux;
    std::vector<char> name;
    int count=0, sum=0; 

    while (count<10) {
        getline(cin, aux);

        for (int i=0; i<aux.length(); i++)  name.push_back(aux[i]);

        for (int i=0; i<name.size(); i++) {
            name[i] = tolower(name[i]);                                 //para garantir que todos os caracteres estão em minúsculo  
            if (name[i] > 96 && name[i] < 123 && name[i] == 32)         //faixa de decimais das letras minúsculas e espaço em caso de nome composto
                sum += name[i];
        }

        char v[name.size()];                                            //vetor auxiliar criado para realizar a conversão de vetor de char para string

        for (int i=0; i<name.size(); i++)   {
            v[i] = name[i];
        }

        while (vet[sum%10] != "\0")                                     //para evitar colisão
            sum++;

        vet[sum%10] = (string) v;                                       //conversão para string e => K mod m = K % m em C++
        cout << vet[sum%10] << endl;
        count++;
        sum = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<name.size(); i++)   v[i] = '\0';

        name.clear();
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)    cout << vet[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Este código está usando o conceito de Hashing para armazenar nomes dentro de um vetor.

Minha pergunta é:

> Sempre que eu tento inserir um nome com 8, 16 ou 24 caracteres, ao
>   converter de um vetor de caracteres para uma string, o compilador
>   sempre coloca outros 3 caracteres em frente ao nome. Se eu tentar
>   inserir um nome com 9, 17 ou 25 caracteres, o compilador sempre coloca
>   outros 2 caracteres em frente ao nome. Se eu tentar inserir um nome
>   com 10, 18 ou 26 caracteres, o compilador sempre coloca outro
>   caractere em frente ao nome.
>
> Por que isso acontece? Existe alguma forma de prevenir isso?

Eu preciso que os nomes sejam exatamente (mas em minúsculo) como eles foram inseridos na entrada, mas organizados de acordo com a lógica Hashing.

Já depurei o código e vi que o problema está na conversão do vetor de caracteres para string, mas ainda não encontrei uma forma melhor de fazer isso.

```
vet[sum%10] = (string) v;
```

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Porque você não faz name ser direto um vetor de char já que você converte pra ele depois? Também não precisa copiar além de 10 posições, já que você vai ignorar.

```
   char name[10];
```

2) Você limita seu nome na string vet a 10 posições, mas tenta copiar nomes com mais caracteres, retornando para o início. Está com cara de que são caracteres que foram truncados aparecendo no início.

Como você comenta que já debugou, imagino que v[i] esteja com a string correta porque você não está fazendo essa lógica de truncamento.

Uma forma melhor de fazer isso seria, depois de converter name para um vetor de char:

```
  snprintf(name, 10, "%s", aux.data());
  std::string buffAsStdStr = name;
```

Comment: Realmente, o problema era na hora de criar o vetor v[name.size()]. Vou dar uma olhada nas suas sugestões para melhorar o código. Muito obrigado pela resposta!